# view health reports in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, site-usage

in sharepoint 2013 why view health reports showing only slowest pages in
http://xxx/_admin/HealthReport.aspx

in this sharepoint farm it configured usage and health data collection service and enabled all event logs .